# Calculating yaw/pitch/roll

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, latitude-longitude, pitch

I have three GPS antennae on a boat. They are in fixed xyz positions relative to each other.

For example:

- Ant1 at (0,0,0)
- Ant2 at (0,5,0)
- Ant3 at (5,2,0)

I want to make a program that will calculate the yaw, pitch and roll as the boat travels. I will have a record of the xyz position for each of the three antennae every second. It will be ascii format in the form:

```
Ant 1 , time in hrsminsec  , lat in degminsec , long degminsec , z in metres
```

For example:

```
235316, LA53.1729289341999986,LN-6.2148456192000000,EL163.7457
```

Ditto for ant2 and ant3.

Comment: I know! It's a trick question. Your boat is on land. It's not going anywhere.

Comment: we have a sonar on board and i need to determine its precise location every second to establish river bed level

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I would be really surprised of the GPS antenna were accurate enough to give you reliable information for this. That is unless you have a massive boat, but then again if the boat is massive it probably won't have much roll to it. GPS are typically only accurate to a few feet (unless they have made massive improvements in the past few years that I am unaware of). Plus you will then need to provide very accurate measurement of your GPS array to the software to make sure things are computed properly. It would probably be a MUCH better and more precise system if you just bought an accelerometer and let it feed the data. It will give you the actual Yaw/Roll/Pitch from a single device and with great accuracy.

This product looks to be exactly what you need given hardware and API it provides for logging precomputed yaw/roll/pitch. I don't have any experience with it, though.

http://www.microstrain.com/3dm.aspx#specs

You could then check the yaw values against the "yaw" values from the GPS (the angle between the line of the boats position at any two points in time and a reference line, like due North) if you wanted to check accuracy.

Good luck and I hope this helps.

Comment: The GPS is survey grade L1 L2 RTK.accuracy is 15 mm XY and 25 mm Z for every position recorded. boat is 10 m long and will be travelling at about 3 knots . also i need pitch and roll in addition to yaw.

Comment: Ok, in that case what you are going to be using are Euler Angles. The code is a bit confusing if you are not familiar with trigonometry, but there is more than likely a class written for whichever language you are coding in. Could you please tag whichever language you plan to use so that we can weigh in on the best practice? Also, what is the orientation of your sensors?

Comment: hi colt i will do detailed reply tonight. i am familar with trig.

Comment: hi Colt this is what files from gps look like

Comment: File from ANT1.
$GPGGA,210426.00,5208.56756982,N,00927.66144941,W,4,07,2,160.000,M,56.000,M,1
where File from ant 2
$GPGGA,210426.00,5208.57296132,N,00927.66162588,W,4,07,2,160.000,M,56.000,M,1
i.e ant2 is 10 metres due north of Ant1 
$GPGGA indicates a gps obtained point ,
 210426.00  indicates Time of point hhmmss.ss
5208.56756982  Lat of pos ddmm.mmmmmmmm
00927.66144941 Lon odf position ddmm.mmmmmmm
4  is  RTK fixed , or 5 would be RTK float
07  is  number of sats used
2 is HDOP ( dilution of precision )
160.00 Alt in metres 
56.000 geoid seperation
1 age of differential corrections seconds

Comment: from ant2
$GPGGA,210426.00,5208.57296132,N,00927.66162588,W,4,07,2,160.000,M,56.000,M,1
i.e ant2 is 10 m N of Ant1 
ant3
$GPGGA,210426.00,5208.57298303,N,00927.65987326,W,4,07,2,160.000,M,56.000,M,1  i.e ant3 is 2 m E of ant2
a sec later three reads say boat has moved forward 5m no change in yaw/roll but change in pitch 5d 15m 39sec deg down
Ant1
$GPGGA,210427.00,5208.57026557,N,00927.66153764,W,4,07,2,160.000,M,56.000,M,1
ant2
$GPGGA,210427.00,5208.57563011,N,00927.66171323,W,4,07,2,159.000,M,56.000,M,1
ant3
$GPGGA,210427.00,5208.57568440,N,00927.65733169,W,4,07,2,160.000,M,56.000,M,1

Comment: Survey grade means they can get very accurate fixes, but how long does it react to position changes? How does that compare to how fast the vessel will be moving? And how much can/will the vessel be moving relative to the receiver error?

Comment: And how much will the vessel be moving relative to the sonar error?

Comment: Hi Andrew very good points. very breifly the GPS receiver can update its position at 2 hz ( twice per secondc ) or at 10 hz ( ten times per second if we enable this option) The boat will be moving quite slow when surveying ( max 5 KM per hour. ) The sonar has an accuracy of approx 100 mm in water depth of 5 m. The main difficulty is handling the huge volume of data generated by the sonar ( 2 GB per hour).  We could if necessary output the GPS positions at twice per second but we are not sure if we could handle the data during processing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use MEMS sensors instead of GPS ? 
Much cheaper, but much more accurate.

This is one of many MEMS sensor demo kits that you can choose :
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2472

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are those three GPS antennas are connected to? If you'll connect it to three GPS receivers you'll wont be able to solve your problem.

You'll need to a commercial vector GPS receiver, which is not cheap.
Many commercial vector GPS devices manufacturers also supply a free software which calculates both location and attitude.

If you're still into writing your own attitude calculation algorithm based on a vector GPS receiver, this paper will help:

http://microsat.sm.bmstu.ru/e-library/Algorithms/GPS/4386.pdf

Comment: Hi Each gps antenna is connected to a seperate survey grade gps receiver. each receiver receives corrections from land based base station by radio. the accuracy of each point surveyed is 15 mm xy and 20 mm Z. the GPS is called PF500 from ashtech.com.  The GPS units calc lat , long and alt. I require yaw, pitch and roll from the redsulting three coords.